# Simple demo for Spring Security with JavaConfig

Tags: spring-security, spring-java-config

My Maven project has some integration tests which need to satisfy some simple in memory Spring security.

I had this XML based configuration which works fine, but now I would like to have it in a JavaConfig based configuration:

```
<!-- A REST authentication -->
<http use-expressions="true" pattern="/admin/**">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <http-basic entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <logout />
</http>

<!-- A hard coded authentication provider -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="stephane" password="mypassword" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

I tried the following Java configuration:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("stephane").password("mypassword").roles("ADMIN");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .httpBasic();
}
```

But a GET request is denied access:
    Failed tests:   testGreetingSucceedsWithCorrectUserCredentials(com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.AdminControllerTest): Status expected:<200> but was:<401>

Any clue ?

Kind Regards,

Stephane Eybert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix the security with the following configuration:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("stephane").password("mypassword").roles("ADMIN");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .httpBasic()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

I was missing the .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint) and the .csrf().disable() configuration.

The tests now pass as expected.